# "Protocol Application Invalid" in CISCO IP PHONE 7940!

Tags: ip, dhcp, tftp, cisco-7900-ip-phones

I have a boot issue in Cisco IP Phone "Protocol Application Invalid." So I want to update my firmware.

I made my PC as TFTP and DHCP Server and connected my PC and IP phone in same vlan, but it is not getting IP address from DHCP.

Any suggestion?

[image]

Comment: DHCP server should provide IP with option 150 which provide information about the TFTP server . are you did so ?

Comment: Please never use an image for text in your question. Copy the text, paste it into your question, and use the Preformatted text feature (`[]`).

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1):

The 7940 IP phone fails to perform the boot process correctly this problem could be

When you examine the sniffer trace between the DHCP server and the phone, you can identify that the phone accepts a DHCP offer from the data VLAN (the native VLAN) instead of the voice VLAN.
full resolution for this problem could be found in this article [IP Phone 7940/7960 Fails to Boot](http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/support/docs/voice-unified-communications/unified-communications-manager-callmanager/67942-phone-boot-fail.html)

Answer (score 0):

I FIXED IT.  I had same problem after I factory reset (it was working fine before).  Can't even get to Setting as button doesn't responded.
The problem is when factory reset (or if you moved phone to another facility), it tried to look for TFTP server which is no longer at the same place as it is assigned as default (as factory reset).

Simple fix is: if you have pf sense, you had direct TFTP server that phone will take.
Go to pfSense/Services/DHCP Server/LAN
in that menu, at TFTP Server, type in address of your Asterisk or FreePBX server location (where tftp server for asterisk is located at).

Then reboot phone.